# How to make my phpbb index the default "index.html" file with Apache2?

Tags: apache2, phpbb

I'm basically a complete novice with Linux and servers, but i do have my website up...sort of. I need to know how to make my default page my phpbb forum.

I believe you SHOULD be able to see my default Apache page here at www.pnweuros.com, i want that address to take me to www.pnweuros.com/phpbb

I've searched for HOURS, but can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have used vBulletin and XenForo and unfortunately have little experience with phpBB. But I do have a solution, redirecting `www.pnweuros.com` to `www.pnweuros.com/phpbb` via **.htaccess**.

1. Create a `.htaccess` file on your root directory, and copy and paste the following code in the file. http://pastebin.com/kP0H4iJw
2. Make the changes to `.htaccess` as instructed by the comments.

NOTE: Comments are anything in the code begining with a `#`.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and report back after i get a deeper issue figured out, the site isn't even online at all right now lol.

Comment: I noticed that, good luck.